# Docker (compose) fails to build container when mounting single file from official Wordpress image

Tags: linux, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm experiencing the problem with mounting files, opposite to directories which works pretty fine. Specific problem is related to the [Wordpress's official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) and file *wp-config.php* (or any other).

Here's the content of **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
web:
  image: wordpress
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./src/wordpress/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    - ./src/wordpress/wp-config.php:/var/www/html/wp-config.php
  environment:
    WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: dummyname
  links:
    - db:mysql
db:
  image: mysql
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dummypass
```

When I run the command **docker-compose up** or **docker run** output is the same:

```
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
WARNING: /var/www/html is not empty - press Ctrl+C now if this is an error!
+ ls -A
wp-config.php
+ sleep 10
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
sed: couldn't edit wp-config.php: not a regular file
```

In both cases, *wp-config.php/* is created, but as directory, not as a file.

Sometimes error might be:

```
ERROR: Cannot start container <container id>: [9] System error: not a directory
```

If I comment the line which is mounting *wp-config.php* file, everything works as expected.

**docker inspect** gives correct info:

```
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
        "/home/dummyuser/projects/dummyproject/src/wordpress/wp-config.php:/var/www/html/wp-config.php:rw"
    ],
...
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Source": "/home/dummyuser/projects/dummyproject/src/wordpress/wp-config.php",
        "Destination": "/var/www/html/wp-config.php",
        "Mode": "rw",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    },
    {
        "Name": "b8649d2edbfb043a05bce96622fbbc1c10b24b9f65736407efe961c3ec550b7a",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/b8649d2edbfb043a05bce96622fbbc1c10b24b9f65736407efe961c3ec550b7a/_data",
        "Destination": "/var/www/html",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
],
```

*Environment:*

```
Linux 3.19.0-56-generic #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 11 11:03:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
docker-compose version 1.5.2, build 7240ff3
```

Things I've tried, and didn't get any results:

- using **docker run** instead of **docker-compose** (equal behavior/results)
- instead of ./src/wordpress to use absolute path, either by naming it or using **$PWD**
- moving project outside of **home** folder
- commenting the line for volume of wp-config.php file, creating container, then stopping it, uncommenting previously commented line, and starting it again

Not quite sure, but when watching on [entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/df190dc9c5752fd09317d836bd2bdcd09ee379a5/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh), if mounting is performed before Wordpress tar archive is extracted to /var/www/html, that might be the reason why *wp-config.php* file (or any other) cannot be found and therefore mounted. With directories, it seems it's not a problem.

Comment: In your docker-compose.yml file, are you attempting to mount the files into the Docker container?

Comment: You might want to clarify the title a little bit, since there are no *mounts* during a Docker *build* process.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a bit more flexible approach, building your own image as follows:

In Your **docker-compose.yml**:

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ~/workspace/wordpress-dir:/var/www/html
  environment:
    WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: dummyname
  links:
    - db:mysql
db:
  image: mysql
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dummypass
```

and then writing in the same folder you **Dockerfile** as follow:

```
FROM wordpress

# Copying wp-content dir files
COPY src/wordpress/wp-content/* /var/www/html/wp-content/
```

After that **You need to build before up, to avoid wordpress-entrypoint replacements, just for the first time**, as follow:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compuse up
```

I think this way to build your container gives you a little more flexibility and also provides a real encapsulation to your wordpress app content.

Regards

Comment: I would say this is different approach of what I've suggested. It makes sense for _wp-content_ directory, but it enforces you to have initial version of _wp-config.php_ file. In both cases, if you depend on initial versions this won't fit, and that's the point where mounting should be used.

Comment: @a.ilic Hello, I'm understanding that you want to avoid the need to have an initial version of the **wp-config.php** file, if this is correct, in the same way, You can take advantage of the flexibility that you get using your own **Dockerfile** adding the following line: 

`RUN "cp /var/www/html/wp-config-sample.php /var/www/html/wp-config.php"`.

After that, You could use environment variables and _sed_ utils to modify your **wp-config.php** file.

Comment: Sure, that's an option. But please, take look at WordPress's [entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/df190dc9c5752fd09317d836bd2bdcd09ee379a5/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh). Your suggestion seems double the work, since it's already done by this script (_wp-config.php_ and _sed_ operations). Solving the error message `sed: couldn't edit wp-config.php: not a regular file` (fully stated in the question above), might be the solution to this problem.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify your need. First, you want to avoid creating a wp-config.php file. Second, you need to persist your changes in your own wp-content. If this is correct I think we can solve part of the problem defining a volume for the web service.  After that we would have to solve our problem about copying wp-content the first time. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. But lets simplify it completely. Imagine you're starting the new Wordpress project. Mounting _wp-content_ folder will give you folder structure where you can just create a new theme/plugin folder and start developing (the same as you've unpacked the Wordpress source and went to _wp-content_ folder). Besides that you'll most probably need _wp-config.php_ so you can switch debug mode or multisite support. Or you'll just need to do some corrections in _.htaccess_ file. Mounting those files (and gets them out-of-the-box, like _wp-content_ folder) is what is problematic here.

Comment: @a.ilic  Understood. The main problem as I see is: _wp-content_ verification and _wp-config.php_ file verification done by _entrypoint_ script, therefore, the way I see (by now) to workaround with this, is to define a volume for all the `/var/www/html` and use `docker-compose build` before to use `docker-compose up` just for the first time.

I've already fixed the _docker-compose.yml_ and the _Dockerfile_ in the answer to work whit this. I tried and It works. Regards.